# Text disappears/ invisible in MS Edge on scroll / pageload / resize

Tags: html, css, flexbox, microsoft-edge

One of my Websites show a strange behavior in MS Edge. The Text only is Visible / Appears if i hover/select the text. On Window Resize or Scrolling the text disappears again.

Maybe the issue has to do with CSS Rotation. The Text only disappears on the slanted areas. In these sections the outer container is rotated 2deg and the inner container (where the content is placed) is rotated -2deg.

[Bug Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCrBy.gif)

Seems that a figure with overflow hidden followed by a text container causes this bug in rotated sections

HTML:

```
<div class="rotate">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="image">
        <figure><img src="https://dummyimage.com/120x120/8492e0/fff" alt="dummy"></figure>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem <br>ipsum</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rotate{
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transform-origin: left center;
  transform: rotate(2deg);
}

.wrapper{
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
}

figure{overflow: hidden}

.image{
    float: left;
}
```

https://codepen.io/biwer-r/pen/gOaLGMg

Comment: Possible workaround, set the rotation from the content container to -2.01 deg

Comment: I tested and it worked with `rotate(-2.01deg)`. So glad that you have solved the issue.